# How to debug Polymer dom-repeat

Tags: polymer, google-chrome-devtools

I am developing a Polymer component that uses `<template is="dom-repeat" items="rows">` to populate a table, and need to debug what is happening in some rows.  In Chrome developer tools I can select the component in the DOM and inspect all of the rows array using `$0.rows`.  But how do I inspect the data for an individual row?  If I select one of the generated row elements, is there any connection between $0 and the array item used to generate the row?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/dom-repeat), you can use the `modelForElement(el)`, `itemForElement(el)` and `keyForElement(el)` functions.

```
this.$.repeater.modelForElement($0)
```

It can be used on any node, not only the top level element of the repeated template. Getting the `this.$.repeater` can be tricky from the Dev tools though. The above would assume a breakpoint inside your element.

As a second option you can take advantage of the fact that each top level element stamped by the repeater gets an additional property called `_templateInstance`. It will contain all the data you need. Remember however that this is internal implementation detail and could change as Polymer evolves. So debug but don't use that in your code.